# Unable to show SQLite data in android app

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm creating a fitness app in which workout data is entered by a user and saved to 2 tables in an SQLite database (TABLE_CARDIO & TABLE_WEIGHTS). Below is the structure of these 2 tables:

```
 public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FitnessTracker.db";
public static final String TABLE_WEIGHTS = "saved_workout_weights";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "DATE";
public static final String COL_3 = "EXERCISE";
public static final String COL_4 = "WEIGHT";
public static final String COL_5 = "REPS";
public static final String COL_6 = "SETS";

public static final String TABLE_CARDIO = "saved_workout_cardio";
public static final String COL_1a = "ID";
public static final String COL_2a = "DATE";
public static final String COL_3a = "TIME";
```

I've used 'SQLite Manager' firefox add on, in which I was able to see that data has successfully been saved to both tables. Now I need to retrieve the data and show it in my app when a button is clicked. So I have this below method with a query to get all saved data from both tables:

```
 public Cursor getWorkoutData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CARDIO + " CROSS JOIN " + TABLE_WEIGHTS + " ON " + TABLE_CARDIO + ".DATE = " + TABLE_WEIGHTS + ".DATE";
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    return result;
}
```

I then have the following method in a different java class which either returns the data found from the query as string values OR returns 'Error: No workouts found' if the query doesn't find any results from my database:

```
public void viewWorkout() {
    btnShowWorkout.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Cursor result = myDb.getWorkoutData();
                    if (result.getCount() == 0) {
                        //show error
                        messageShow("Error","No workouts found");
                        return;
                    }

                    StringBuffer bfr = new StringBuffer();
                    while (result.moveToNext()) {
                        bfr.append("Id :"+ result.getString(0)+"\n");
                        bfr.append("Date :"+ result.getString(1)+"\n");
                        bfr.append("Time :"+ result.getString(2)+"\n\n");
                        bfr.append("Id :"+ result.getString(0)+"\n");
                        bfr.append("Date :"+ result.getString(1)+"\n");
                        bfr.append("Exercise :"+ result.getString(2)+"\n");
                        bfr.append("Weight :"+ result.getString(3)+"\n");
                        bfr.append("Reps :"+ result.getString(4)+"\n");
                        bfr.append("Sets :"+ result.getString(5)+"\n\n");
                    }

                    //show data
                    messageShow("Past Workouts",bfr.toString());
                }
            }
    );
}
```

My issue is that my app returns the 'Error: No workouts found' even though I have checked my database tables and both are populated. Is there an issue with my query that's not allowing me to get all the data? Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried changing your query?  Something simple like "SELECT * FROM saved_workout_weights"

Comment: Please share data sample. The issue is likely because you cannot join your result set, not because of your code. The way you store `DATE` is of particular interest.

Answer (score 0):

Try using .moveToFirst.  If it returns false, and you are sure you have data in the database, and the tables have been created, something is wrong with your query.

```
if (!result.moveToFirst) {
                    //show error
                    messageShow("Error","No workouts found");
                    return;
                }
```